# Retornar valor de un select option

Tags: php, html

estoy intentando retornar los valores guardados por el usuario en la base de datos de un select option, pero al retornarlo me devuelve todos seleccionados. En base de datos el campo que tiene guardado es Senior que es el que deberia sacar, pero me aparece Otro.

Archivo .php

```
 if ($order_autors == 'Senior'){
   $selected = "selected";
   print_r("Senior");
 }
 if($order_autors == 'Primero'){
   $selected = "selected";
 }
 if($order_autors == 'Segundo'){
   $selected = "selected";
 }
 if($order_autors == 'Otro'){
  $selected = "selected";
 }
 if($order_autors == 'Corresponding'){
  $selected = "selected";
 }
 if($order_autors == 'default'){
  $selected = "selected";
}

echo "<select name='autors_$id' id='autors_$id' required>";
      echo "<option value='default' $selected>Elige una opción</option>";
      echo "<option value='Primero' $selected>Primero/Co-Primero</option>";
      echo "<option value='Senior' $selected>Senior/Co-Senior</option>";
      echo "<option value='Segundo' $selected>Segundo</option>";
      echo "<option value='Corresponding' $selected>Corresponding Autor/Co-Corresponding Autor</option>";
      echo "<option value='Otro' $selected>Otro</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Siempre me devuelve "Otro"

Comment: Estás utilizando la misma variable para todos. Entonces cuando uno esté seleccionado, todos tendrán la selección. Usa diferentes variables o haz la comparación en el `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza algo asi:

```php
$opciones = [
    'default' => 'Elige una opción',
    'Primero' => 'Primero/Co-Primero',
    'Senior' => 'Senior/Co-Senior',
    'Segundo' => 'Segundo',
    'Corresponding' => 'Corresponding Autor/Co-Corresponding Autor',
    'Otro' => 'Otro'
];

$salida_opciones = '';  // inicialización salida opciones

foreach($opciones as $opcion => $descripcion) {
    if($opcion == $order_autors) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    
    $salida_opciones .= '<option value="'.$opcion.'" '.$selected.'>'.$descripcion.'</option>';
}

echo "
<select name='autors_$id' id='autors_$id' required>
    $salida_opciones
</select>
";
```

**Explicación:**

Lo primero que hacemos es generar un array (denominado `$opciones` en este caso) con todos los pares de valores (`value` del **option**) con su descripción.

Después lo recorremos con un `foreach` asignando la opción y la descripción a sendas variables con el mismo nombre.

Durante la iteración comprobamos si la opción es coincidente con la variable `$order_autors` , y en ese caso asignamos el valor `selected` a la variable `$selected`. En caso contrario la dejamos vacia. Así solo marcaremos una en lugar de todas las opciones o ninguna si aun no tenemos nada seleccionado previamente o que nos venga dado por la variable `$order_autors`, en este caso se mostrará la primera del array, que es `default`.

El siguiente paso dentro de la iteración es generar la línea de salida de la opción completa y la vamos concatenando en la variable `$salida_opciones`, inicializada previamente al bucle para que nunca de error si la variable `$opciones` (tipo *array*) no tuviera elementos.

Cuando terminamos ya podemos poner la variable `$salida_opciones` dentro del `<select>` para que agrege todas las opciones en el orden estipulado en el array inicial y con la selección coincidente de `$order_autors` marcada como `selected` de forma única.

El error del codigo de la pregunta, tal como han señalado en los comentarios de la misma, es el uso indebido de la variable `$selected` en todas las opciones, la cual era asignada en cualquiera de los condicionales y escrita en todas las opciones, siendo la última, `Otros` la que acababa mostrandose en la salida final.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás utilizando la misma variable (`$selected`) para todas las opciones del `select`. Entonces cuando una esté seleccionada, todas las opciones acabarán teniendo el atributo `selected`.

Para solucionar el problema cambiando el mínimo de código posible, podrías optar por dos opciones:

> Nota: estas soluciones no son ideales. Es lo más próximo al código que hay en la pregunta, realizando los mínimos cambios posibles. Hay soluciones mejores que ésta.

- Tener una variable por cada opción. Pero puede ser un poco molesto a la hora de añadir nuevas opciones o si el sistema es dinámico.
- Poner la comprobación del selected en el `echo`. En cuyo caso no necesitarías la variable auxiliare `$selected`.

La segunda opción sería algo como esto:

```php
$id = 1;

echo "<select name='autors_$id' id='autors_$id' required>";
echo "<option value='default'>Elige una opción</option>";
echo "<option value='Primero' " . ($order_autors == 'Primero' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Primero/Co-Primero</option>";
echo "<option value='Senior' " . ($order_autors == 'Senior' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Senior/Co-Senior</option>";
echo "<option value='Segundo' " . ($order_autors == 'Segundo' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Segundo</option>";
echo "<option value='Corresponding' " . ($order_autors == 'Corresponding' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Corresponding Autor/Co-Corresponding Autor</option>";
echo "<option value='Otro' " . ($order_autors == 'Otro' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Otro</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

La idea es que para cada opción tiene sun operador terciario que comprueba si la opción es la seleccionada. Si lo es, añade el atributo `selected`; si no, no añade nada.